# how to find all child with id and parent id structure

Tags: mysql, json

**my tabale data is:**

```
  -- ----------------------------
  -- Table structure for abr_cat
  -- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `abr_cat` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `ParentID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of abr_cat
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('22', 'cat 1', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('23', 'sub cat 1-1', '22', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('24', 'sub cat 1-2', '22', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('25', 'sub cat 1-1-1', '23', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('26', 'cat 2', '0', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('27', 'sub cat 2-1', '26', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('28', 'sub cat 1-1-1-1', '25',  '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('29', 'sub cat 1-1-1-1-1', '28', '1');
INSERT INTO `abr_cat` VALUES ('30', 'cat 3', '0', '1');
```

for example i want to find all child of ID=22 and this output:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 23,
        "title": "sub cat 1-1",
        "ParentID": 22,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 24,
        "title": "sub cat 1-2",
        "ParentID": 22,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 25,
        "title": "sub cat 1-1-1",
        "ParentID": 23,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 28,
        "title": "sub cat 1-1-1-1",
        "ParentID": 25,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 29,
        "title": "sub cat 1-1-1-1-1",
        "ParentID": 28,
        "status": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No OP needs to iterate to next data based on the previous data

Comment: @MaathiYosi yes
SELECT * FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID = 22 UNION SELECT * FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ID FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID = 22 )

Comment: You Can add one more level SELECT * FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID = 22 UNION SELECT * FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ID FROM abr_cat WHERE ParentID = 22 ) UNION Select * from abr_cat where PARENT_ID IN (SELECT PARENT_ID FROM abr_cat where PARENT_ID IN (SELECT PARENT_ID FROM abr_cat where PARENT_ID IN (SELECT PARENT_ID FROM abr_cat where ID =22)))

Comment: @mb that would mean each time there is a new level you would have to update your query.

Comment: @mb tree level not static

Comment: @mb tree level not static

Comment: Yaah that is the issue with this solution need to think of a different way to make it dynamic

Comment: of child to parent is ok
but i want parent to all child

child to parent query is:
select  t2.ID ,t2.title 
FROM
(select @r as _id,(select @r :=ParentID from abr_cat WHERE ID=_id ) as parent_id,@l :=@l+1 as lvl from (SELECT @r :=29,@l:=0) vars, abr_cat m WHERE @r<>0 ) t1 join abr_cat t2 on t1._id=t2.ID ORDER BY t1.lvl DESC;

Answer (score 0):

try this query and join will be helpful:

```
   SELECT a.title FROM
   `abr_cat`  as a left join `abr_cat` as b 
    on b.`ParentID` = a.`ID` where a.`ParentID` =22
```

Screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/jm06li